# Unable to wait for AWS RDS db rename operation to complete (WaiterError)

Tags: boto3, amazon-rds

I want to rename an existing mysql db in AWS RDS

```
import boto3
rds_client = boto3.client('rds')
target_reports_db = "myproject"
rds_client.modify_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=target_reports_db,
        ApplyImmediately=True,
        NewDBInstanceIdentifier=f"{target_reports_db}-to-drop")
rds_waiter = rds_client.get_waiter('db_instance_available')
rds_waiter.wait(DBInstanceIdentifier=f"{target_reports_db}-to-drop")
```

However it throws an error:

```
[ERROR] WaiterError: Waiter DBInstanceAvailable failed: DBInstance myproject-to-drop not found.
```

Why boto3 throws this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the reported issue for boto3 library https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/609

Comment: Relevant quote: "It is essentially a limitation in the waiter specification, where once we hit a success state we stop waiting. There is no current way [...] without revamping our design of waiters."